# Interpreting regression model with delta(change in) as dependent variable

Tags: regression

Lets assume the model is `Δy = x1 + x2 +...xn` where Δy = yt - yt-1. But independent variables are not in delta form. How to interpret this model ?

Edit: To make it more clear, I'll add some details where I am confused. if the model was `Δy = Δx1 + Δx2 +...Δxn`, it will considered first difference model and I know how to interpret them. But I have seen papers where only the dependent variable is delta(difference) form and independent variable are not ([This paper uses this kind of model)](https://academic.oup.com/rof/article/23/5/935/5066354).
I am unable to understand how the betas on Xs in this model will be interpreted.

Matthieu Chavaz, Andrew K Rose, Political Borders and Bank Lending in Post-Crisis America, *Review of Finance*, Volume 23, Issue 5, September 2019, Pages 935–959, https://doi.org/10.1093/rof/rfy027

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: I edited your question to include a full citation to your paper. I suggest that you make further edits to describe the model in the paper. Then it will become clear that several predictors do vary in time; there are some lagged variables as well.